# How to split other information from binary string?

Tags: python, image, stdout, labview

I have an image which is a result of a python code and has to be shown in a LabVIEW program. The pixels of the image are sent ( with sys.stdout.buffer.write)as a U32 pixels string, so I used unflatten from string in LabVIEW code to show the image, but the result from python includes other information as shown in the picture below, when I split them "manually" I can get the right picture. My question is, how can I only get the pixels information from python output to get the picture.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it raw pixel information, or does it contain some meta information (Pixel format, resolution, bits per pixel)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it is raw pixel information, but since it is an ouput from a python code ( deep learning test code) so it includes some other information such as the steps iteration, what causes the error.

Comment: Depending on the performance requirement, you can use match pattern VI to slice it. Match between 'step\r\n' and the next counter ('1/1' in this case)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `match pattern` node twice to cut off the first two lines like this:
[image: code sample]

Note that you might need to replace `\n` with `\r\n`, depending on how your actual input is coded.